# One word to describe "one hair that grows on someone's bald head"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a single English word for **a single hair** that grows on someone's head which is practically bald?

I found a picture like this [one](http://www.google.com/imgres?safe=active&sa=X&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=642&tbm=isch&tbnid=zvgKYsI5Rn1B3M:&imgrefurl=http://www.visitpenang.gov.my/portal3/events-of-the-year/details/367-dream-date-with-upin-a-ipin.html?pop=1&tmpl=component&docid=jeMm8hHt6StS1M&imgurl=http://www.visitpenang.gov.my/portal3/images/stories/upin.png&w=575&h=1234&ei=3tjCUqWeDIn_lAXAqYDADQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:10,s:0,i:111&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=174&tbnw=81&start=0&ndsp=18&tx=25&ty=50), this is a movie character:

[image]

See that one hair? Is there an English word that describes that **hair**? [Not just that is *one*, but also *a hair*.]

Comment: Single, lone, only, solitary, etc.

Comment: It looks more like a *lock* of hair than a solitary hair.  Perhaps it's a baby Cossack, and it has what the Russians call хохол.

Comment: That looks thicker than a single *follicle* or a *strand* - in fact its more like a small *tuft*.

Comment: How about "lonely"?

Comment: Janus: Aren't those terms for "one" only? Not "one hair",
Z7sg: Do you mean *lock* in terms of locks in doors?

Autoresponder: Tuft? :D Anyway are those terms suitable for hair? Like *a hair strand* or *a tuft of hair*?
Elliot: Haha, I don't know if that suits that kind of hair,,

Comment: Is there a word for it in your native language?

Comment: A die hard follicle? :P

Comment: @Mitch, I think there is. The problem is I can't remember what it is. Dominic: Yea right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a strand? I suppose you could complicate things by adding such words as *single* and *solitary*, but a strand is a strand; *single* and *solitary* would seem, then, to be redundant (though an argument could be made that *strand* needs the word *one* or *a* to accompany it, since to say "He has strand of hair" would not sound right).

Comment: *A strand of hair*, you mean? Does *strand* have the same meaning as *a strand of hair* or *a hair strand*?

Comment: @Safira: Yeah. Using simply "strand" to refer to a single hair is a bit of a stretch. Moreover, a strand is not limited to hair, of course, but also includes fibers, threads, filaments, strings and the like.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably call it a [Charlie Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Brown), and many Americans would get what you meant.

Comment: You mean *Charlie Brown's hair* or just *Charlie Brown* would make a meaning of *that one hair*?